# Lost changes to a JavaScript file in my documents on Windows 8 after Auto Repair

Tags: windows-8, restore

I was working on a web application in Visual Studio (an IDE). It automatically saves my progress as I work on the site, when I launch it for testing.

After a while of working on the app, my computer fails to load when I restart it and it brings up Auto Repair tool. I choose <kbd>Restore</kbd> and it takes a while to do it so I shut it down and attempt again (several times). Then I decide to wait for system restore to complete (for a **long** time) and it succeeds.

I am able to access log into Windows 8 as usual but there are many weird things happening such as missing files from some folders on the Desktop, and now I realize that a week's work on some JavaScript file has been lost.

I don't have File History enabled.

What happened and how can I retrieve the newer content? *Update*: this was caused by <kbd>Restore</kbd>, so the question now becomes:

*Why did System Restore change my JavaScript file and other non-System files? It shouldn't right?*

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue laughing out loud. I was going to go nuts.

It was INDEED System Restore invoked form the Windows 8 Automatic Repair Tool. I doubted it at first because it specifically says that it doesn't touch user files.

So I used System Restore from control panel to restore my computer to a point that had luckily been created by chance when I installed a program (coincidentally Virtual PC).

From now on, I'll back up everything! Probably get a new PC too to distribute tasks between my laptops.

Pphheeww.

Comment: If you are working on source code, you should be storing it in a repository. Check out something like github. There should never be a case where you have a week's worth of work uncommitted.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton - At the very least one should use something like Skydrive, Google Drive, Dropbox.

Comment: I totally agree with you both. But do you guys have any idea why would System Restore mess with me JavaScript file? I noticed it didn't touch some other CSHTML file. Thanks guys.

Comment: An edit to the question brings me back here. Regarding git, I used to use it for "projects" only, but now I use it for almost all but the simplest of files. So if I work on something for more than a couple of hours, git init.